# How to have Quicklist item launch in a Path?

Tags: unity, launcher, quicklists

In a .desktop file you can specify the `Path` key in a [Desktop Entry] so that the working directory will be that path when the `Exec` is launched. However, this key does not seem to work when launching items from Quicklist even though the `Path` key is set in the [Desktop Action] group. Am I doing something wrong or does Unity not support this yet?

If there's no way to do this, can I change the Exec key in some way to get the same effect?

**EDIT:** 
For testing purposes, here's an example little script (displaycwd.py) that when run displays the current working path in a Gtk window. There's an example .desktop file that follows showing that when run normally through the Launcher it opens with the right path (/home/ian/Documents in my case). However, activating it through a quicklist, displays the user directory (/home/ian in my case) instead. Just make sure to put the script somewhere in your $PATH.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from gi.repository import Gtk
import os

pwd=os.path.realpath(os.curdir)

win=Gtk.Window()
label=Gtk.Label(pwd)
win.add(label)
win.show_all()
win.connect('destroy', Gtk.main_quit)
Gtk.main()
```

And the .desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Display Working Directory
Exec=displaycwd.py
Type=Application
Actions=quicklist
Path=/home/ian/Documents
Icon=folder

[Desktop Action quicklist]
Name=QL Display WD
Exec=displaycwd.py
Path=/home/ian/Documents
```

Comment: The problem isn't executing the program, it's setting the working directory so that the program will find the correct libraries and icons it will need once running. I need this to be a general property so it will work with other people's programs that I don't have control over. If there was a prefix to add on the Exec line to mimic this behavior, that might work.

Comment: Submited a bug report to Unity about this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/1113883

Comment: FYI this will fix your issue: https://code.launchpad.net/~3v1n0/libindicator/shortcut-path-key/+merge/179149

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found a way around that, since it seems that the quicklist ignores the path and other variables, we can create a script that changes the directory, then executes your program.

1. Create a file called `cd.sh` or title of your choice, In that file use the following text:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   cd /home/ian/Documents
   displaycwd.py
   ```
2. Mark the file as executable, Right-Click > Properties > Permissions > Allow this file to run as Program.

   Or in terminal:

   ```
   chmod +x cd.sh
   ```
3. Place `cd.sh` in the same location you have `displaycwd.py` and change the Quicklist to:

   ```
   [Desktop Action quicklist]
   Name=QL Display WD
   Exec=cd.sh
   ```

   This makes the quicklist first call a shell-script that changes the directory, then runs your program.

---

### Solution #2

After looking around I think you can change the `Exec` line to this:

```
Exec=bash -c "cd /home/ian/Documents && displaycwd.py"
```

To pass a string through bash, that changes the directory then runs your program.

Comment: This won't work for me... I can't predict what application a user will need to run and generate custom scripts for them on the fly to put in a launcher. For personal use though, this would be just fine.

Comment: I think I found another workaround that would only use the launcher file, edited in to end of answer.

Comment: Props to you for the best available answer. Hope Unity will support in future.